# C++ Coveralls show that files are covered but they are not

Tags: c++, gcc, coveralls

I am using GCC compiler with `-g -O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage` flags. It generates `*.gcda` files of the source code files which has tests. I am using [github.com/eddyxu/cpp-coveralls](https://github.com/eddyxu/cpp-coveralls) for coverage upload.

The problem is that Coveralls shows that files **are 100% covered** but, actually, they **are not** covered. In this case only `src/utils/language.cpp` has tests and Coveralls shows proper result.

What should I do that Coveralls could show **0%** instead of **100%**?

[image: Covered files in Coveralls]

Comment: That's because, according to coverall, there are no source lines in those modules that generate any code. You can argue that covering all of zero lines of code yields 100 percent coverage.

Comment: So, am I right by saying this: source code will be covered 0% if it is linked in `tests` executable, otherwise, it will be 100%?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.